# DeprecationWarning for "if x:"?

Tags: python, pep8

The question I'm about to ask here [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420934) been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216681), but those questions/answers make no mention of what I want to know.

I recall a few months or so ago, I had a rather sizable Python script, and I was using `if x:` because it was shorter and I was lazy. I don't remember which version of Python, but I do remember getting a `DeprecationWarning` (or `PendingDeprecationWarning`?) about implicit comparisons to `True`.

Now, I'm trying to write [something](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16) *someone else* might read. I'm using `if x == True` and `if x is not None` everywhere, and `pep8` and `pylint` are complaining about this, saying I should use `if x:`.

Personally, I think `if x:` is far less readable, but `pep8` (the program) and [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (the document) both disagree.

Google is not being very helpful in allowing me to figure in which version, if ever, Python gave a `DeprecationWarning` for `if x:`, so I wonder if perhaps the SO community can provide insight.

Should I be worrying about this at all? Does it actually matter that much?

Comment: Did you try `if 1:`? The if condition still holds. I prefer `if x==True`.[*Explicit is better than implicit*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: In the script that was giving the warning, what was the type of `x`?  It may be the library that defines that type has deprecated conversion to `bool`.

Comment: @BhargavRao I know how `==` and `is` and comparisons to `True` and `None` *work*, that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: Well, this is pretty much arguing about taste. `PEP-8` is a style suggestion, and a good one at that. But it is in no way a requirement, so you are definitely allowed to deviate if you feel it improves readability. Just be consistent about it! From `import this`: _Readability counts._

Comment: @jwodder The script doesn't use any non-builtin types, just strings, ints and bools.

Comment: @N.Wouda well, when I'm confident with the completeness of this script I intend to post it to [CodeReview.SE] (and not get a going-over for not being PEP 8 compliant), and I *like* `pep8` and its guidelines.

Comment: `if x:` is perfectly standard Python, and the preferred form when `x` is boolean. It *has* to be some kind of class that was generating the error.

Comment: @cat: it is perfectly good Python, and Python 3.+ versions don't give a warning, so if you're writing code for other people to work with in the future, using `if x:` is perfectly fine.  And by the way, on behalf of every developer who had to maintain horribly unreadable code, THANK YOU for considering the readability of your code.  :)

Comment: @gariepy post that as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly good Python, and Python 3.+ versions don't give a warning, so if you're writing code for other people to work with in the future, using `if x:` is perfectly fine. And by the way, on behalf of every developer who had to maintain horribly unreadable code, THANK YOU for considering the readability of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer as to what condition to use is, in the first place, a matter of semantics rather than style.  Unless x is a boolean value, 0/False or 1/True, which your question did not specify, `if x:` and `if x == True:` are semantically different conditions and often give different results.  You should use whichever is the correct one for the situation.  `if x:` is usually the correct choice, but not always. If x is specified (known) to be a boolean, then adding `== True` is superfluous and a waste of time for the writer, reader, and interpreter.

Under the covers, `if x:` means (is implemented as) `if bool(x) is True` in the normal meaning of this expression, and `if x == True:` means `if bool(x == True) is True`.  Since `x == True` return a bool and bool(a_bool) is a_bool, the latter reduces to `if (x == True) is True`.  In general, `bool(x)` is not the same as `x == True`.

`if x is None:` (or `not None`) should be used if and only if that is the proper condition.  It often correct when testing the output of a function returns either an int (or string or ...) or None.  In many other situations, it is usually wrong.

Comment: I know the *technical* difference; that's not my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several separate issues confused.

It's best to check what the style guide *actually* says, and double check how your code *actually* behaves, rather than relying only on remembered behaviour :-)

### Boolean expressions are already either true or false

The expression in an `if` statement is *always* intepreted as boolean; anyone reading Python code needs to know that anyway.

So the following all mean exactly the same thing, and piling on `== True` does not improve readability:

```python
if x + y:
    …

if (x + y) == True:
    …

if ((x + y) == True) == True:
    …

if (((x + y) == True) == True) == True:
    …
```

which is why PEP 8 says:

> Don't compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==` .

### Singletons should be compared using identity

The comparison of an object to `None` implies that value is treated specially; it is commonly used as a sentinel for special processing. It is a singleton, so comparing whether an object is merely *equal to* `None` is ambiguous.

So, if your intent is to test a value for `None`, you should test whether the object *is* none by testing its identity:

```python
if x is None:
    …

if x is not None:
    …
```

which is why PEP 8 says:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not , never the equality operators.

### `None` is not the only value that is boolean false

There are many values which are false in a boolean context, so doing a mere `if x:` is not enough to tell whether an object is actually `None`.

Which is why PEP 8 says:

> beware of writing if x when you really mean if x is not None -- e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other value.